# 2006, 'MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
wait_timeout=200000
interactive_timeout = 200000
```

I have changed these values,but the error is so.

Comment: Could you tell me what version of mysql you use and when you obtain the error "mysql server has gone away". I tested on my mysql server by adding in my mysqld.cnf file the same three lines and restart my server and no problem appear. My version of mysql server is : 5.7.17-log Best regards,

Comment: Can you confirm that your mysql server is pointing at the same config file you are editing? Its easy to edit a config file it isn't using.